# Which is the better layout? Matrix layout or Form?

Tags: sapui5

I am using both matrix layout and Form in my application. I am preferring Form for better alignment. But I have doubts on this,  which Layout is preferable and why?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically both are similar, but if you want own alignments and sizes I would advice you to use a Vertical Layout and use CSS-Classes and a Grid System to align the Controls.

If you want to choose solely between Matrix and Form, then go with Form! It's the easiest to implement and the alignments are set up to hold an application in a nice way.

Answer (score 1):

Generally , I prefer Grid Layout and GridData as LayoutData of its content.

```
        /*FormGroup1*/
        var oFromGroup1=new sap.ui.layout.Grid("oFromGroup1",{
            hSpacing: 1,
            vSpacing: 1, 
            layoutData:new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span:"L12 M12 S12"})
        });
        var oNameLabel=new sap.ui.commons.Label({
            text:"Name",
            layoutData:new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span:"L4 M4 S12"})
        });
        var oNameText=new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
            value:"Jibin Joy",
            width:"100%",
            layoutData:new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span:"L8 M8 S12"})
        });
        var oDobLabel=new sap.ui.commons.Label({
            text:"DOB",
            layoutData:new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span:"L4 M4 S12",linebreak:true})
        });
        var oDobDatePicker=new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker({
            yyyymmdd:"19890121",
            width:"100%",
            layoutData:new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span:"L8 M8 S12"})
        });
        oFromGroup1.addContent(oNameLabel);
        oFromGroup1.addContent(oNameText);
        oFromGroup1.addContent(oDobLabel);
        oFromGroup1.addContent(oDobDatePicker);

oFromGroup1.placeAt(this);
```

Please check out:

[Grid Layout](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.Grid.html)
and
[GridData](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.GridData.html)